# how to record sound for cocos2d-x V.3 for iOS?

Tags: ios, audio, cocos2d-x, recording

I'm developing a game by cocos2d-x V.3.x, I want to record player's sound using iPad's mic, but I cannot import AVFoundation.h. It links to many errors due to OBJC and C++ language problem?

How can I integrate AVFoundation to cocos2d-x? or any sound engine that can help doing audio recording and replay for cocos2d-x?